# After the Java 21 release, does the thread pool need to update for the virtual thread? ex: netty? jedis? OKHttp? DB?

Tags: java, java-21, virtual-threads

As you know, The most important upgrade is Virtual Thread in Java 21. However many open-source components are based on Java 8, so the platform thread is currently implemented. suppose I want to try the virtual thread with Netty Jedis Okhttp dbpool. do we need to update the source for them (netty jedis ...)?

I just have the plan, and I have no idea to do that

Comment: You don't need to change anything, unless you want to use virtual threads.  But if you want to use them, that will entail a code change.  So ... if you wanted (say) Netty to use virtual threads you would need to upgrade to a version of Netty that does this.  Ditto for all of the others.

Comment: If (say) Netty doesn't support virtual threads yet, the simplest approach is to wait until it does.  You should be able to do this piecemeal ... so that you don't have to upgrade all of the components at once.  But YMMV : I've not had to do this.

Comment: For all frameworks supporting to provide your own `Executor`/`ExecutorService`, you can provide one creating virtual threads. However, virtual threads are not a magic bullet, executing arbitrary unadapted code in virtual threads can even degrade the performance. It’s more than just activating a switch.